# John and Jane are taking the cards from the well mixed pack of $16$ cards. What is the probability that John in the hands has card of boy?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, card-games

John and Jane are taking the cards from the well mixed pack of $16$ cards. In pack of cards are $4$ aces $(A)$, $4$ kings $(K)$, $4$ queens $(Q)$ and $4$ boys $(J)$. First John take one card from the top of the pack. But if he take a boy then he quickly, before Jane see, take another card and return card with boy on the top of the pack. Otherwise he keep the card. What is the probability that John in the hands has card of boy?

So my solution is $$P(\text{John in the hands has card of boy}) = 1/4$$

Is that correct?

Comment: This is now the fourth place where you're posting these "subquestions". Please don't spread identical questions over various places on the site. Also please don't modify questions with new "follow-up" questions after the original question has been answered (and in fact you accepted the answer).

Comment: I delete. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't show any effort solving it, and adds "My solution is..." just for the appearance, as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666909/131263) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666949/131263), posted by the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, since John takes a look at his first card, we should condition on the event $J_1$ i.e. the event that the first card is $J$. If his first card is boy (event $J_1$ with probability $4/16$) then he changes to a second card different from the first. So, there is now a $3/15$ chance to draw a boy again. Contrary, if his first card is not a boy (event $J_1^c$ with probability $12/16$) he keeps it and therefore there is $0$ probability that he will land with a boy in his hands in this case. Lets denote with $J_2$ that the final card is a boy. Putting these together, we then have \begin{align}P(J_2)&=P(J_2\mid J_1)P(J_1)+P(J_2\mid J_1^c)P(J_1^c)=\frac{3}{15}\cdot\frac{4}{16}+0\cdot\frac{12}{16}=\frac{12}{240}=\frac1{20}\end{align}

Comment: Preferably and to get a valid answer post them as new questions.

Answer (score 1):

No, that would be the probability if John couldn't swap the first card in case it was a $J$.

Note that John has a $J$ if and only if both top cards were $J$. The probability for this is

$$
\frac{\binom42}{\binom{16}2}=\frac{4\cdot3}{16\cdot15}=\frac1{20}\;.
$$

Comment: @julio77: You just posted that first comment as a separate question. Please don't post questions spread out over various places; it wastes time and effort when people don't see the progress others have made. Also, posting it as a separate new question was the preferred way; follow-up questions in comments tend to lead to long comment threads. So I'll look at your question there. You might want to ask the second one as a separate question, too; I won't be answering it here.

Comment: @julio77: I see now that you also posted these questions as comments under Jimmy's answer. Please take a moment to reflect on how this site works and how people's time will be wasted if you spread identical questions around like that.