# $16$ cards. What is the conditional probability, that initially John took this card of boy?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, card-games

John and Jane are taking the cards from the well mixed pack of $16$ cards. In pack of cards are $4$ aces (A), $4$ kings (K), $4$ queens (Q) and $4$ boys (J). First John take one card from the top of the pack. But if he take a boy then he quickly, before Jane see, take another card and return card with boy on the top of the pack. Otherwise he keep the card.

Question
Let say that Jane have a boy. What is the conditional probability, that initially John took this card of boy? My solution is $3/28$. Is that correct?

Comment: Do you mean John initially got a card showing a boy?

Comment: Yes, John initially took a card of boy

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP doesn't show any effort solving it, and adds "My solution is..." just for the appearance, as in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666862/131263) and [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1666909/131263), posted by the same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As calculated in the answers to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666909) (which, by the way, it would be good to link to in such a case of related questions), the probability for Jane to take a J is $\frac9{20}$. The probability for Jane to take a J that John took is simply the probability that John took a J, i.e. $\frac14$. Thus the conditional probability is

$$
\frac{\frac14}{\frac9{20}}=\frac59\;.
$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability that John has taken a boy and then Jane takes that boy is $\frac{4}{16}=\frac14$

---

The probability that John has taken a non-boy and then Jane takes a boy is $\frac{12}{16}\cdot\frac{4}{15}=\frac15$

---

Hence the probability that Jane takes the boy that John has taken is $\frac{\frac14}{\frac14+\frac15}=\frac59$

Comment: The probability of picking the same boy certainly cannot exceed $\frac14$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: But it is already known that Jane has picked a boy, so we need to calculate the chances that it is the same boy previously picked by John.

Comment: Oh wait, I misread  - there is no additional shuffling before Jane draws a card. *If* John pocks a jack, then Jane *automatically* picks that